# Llenar matriz empezando por filas y después las columnas

Tags: java

Tengo una duda con el uso de *for* para llenar una matriz de un boleto de lotería, lo que quería hacer es una función que llene una matriz de 10x5 con números del 1 al 49, Que la primera posición que seria la posición [0,0] sea 0.

```
private static void omplirAposta(int bulleta[][]){
    //Contador que va sumando 1 al 49
    int i =0;
        
    for (int row=0;row<bulleta.lenght;row++){
        for (int col=0;col<bulleta[row].length;i++){
            //lleno la matriz  
            bulleta[row][col]=i++;
        }
    }
}
    
public static void main(String[] args){
    //Declaramos la bulleta que queremos rellenar
    int bulleta [][]= new int[10][5];
        
    // llamo a la funcion encargada de llenar la bulleta
    omplirAposta(bulleta);
}
```

La salida que busco es esta, pero no consigo  hacerlo correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy poco desesperado porque no sale una cosa tan fácil, si alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Primero que nada, cuando haces una pregunta es necesario que nos proporciones ***todo el código relacionado con la misma***. Tal cual está tu pregunta (y sin haber especificado exactamente *cual es el error*) podría responderte que no funciona porque la variable `x` que incrementas en el bucle no está declarada. Yo no puedo ver todo el código, si asumo que solo tienes lo que hay ahí, hay demasiadas incógnitas para responder correctamente... Te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] si quieres entender cómo funciona SO y cómo elaborar una pregunta *correctamente*

Comment: Dicho eso, el principal problema que veo es la condición de tu bucle `for`: `i<m[row].lenght`, basicamente estás diciendo que quieres que el bucle for se ejecute siempre que la `i` valga menos que la longitud de cada fila, es decir, 5? Eso solo ejecutará tu bucle 5 veces... debes **replantearte** la condición de tu bucle. Por ejemplo, que se ejecute mientras `i` sea menor al *total* de casillas, o hacer dos bucles uno dentro del otro para recorrer cada columna de cada fila, que sería lo más fácil creo.

Comment: Primero de todo mcuhas grascias por ajudarme, ja cambiado un poco el codigo para explicarme mejor, lo que no entiendo como llenar la matatrices con numeros continuos 1, 49 de manera que sale la foto

Answer (score 5):

La solución a tu problema es sencillo, pues sólo debes cambiar el orden de insercción de la fila por la columna de la siguiente forma:

```
    // Declaramos la matriz con 10 filas y 5 columnas
    Integer[][] matriz = new Integer[10][5];
    // Declaramos un valor para cada columna, yo he escogido este para adaptarlo a tu imagen
    int k = 0;
    // El orden real de i serían las filas y de j las columnas, pero como quieres inversa, 
    // se pone como al contrario, j es la fila e i las columnas.
    for(int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0;j < 10;j++)
      {
        matriz[j][i] = k;
        k++;
      }
    }
    
    // Una vez rellenados, podemos ir mostrando los datos. 
    // Por consola te saldrán los números por filas
    for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0;j < 5;j++)
      {
        // Con un print en vez de un println, te permite mostrar la matriz como en tu foto
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
      }
      // Y con esto, añadimos un salto de línea
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
```